# Update setInterval value, with interval for itself (Not generating a random number)

Tags: jquery, delay, setinterval, updating

With `jQuery` I am *changing* `iframe` `src`, every **60 sec** *(This works fine)*.

*My `jQuery`:*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var array = ['http://link1.com', 'http://link2.com', 'http://link3.com'];
  var locations = array;
  var len = locations.length;
  var iframe = $('#frame');
  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function () {
        iframe.attr('src', locations[++i]);
  }, 60000);

});
```

*My `iframe`:*

```
<iframe id="frame" src="http://link.com"></iframe>
```

My `iframe src` function works fine and what I would like to achieve is, instead of having a *fixed* `delay` number *(now 60 sec)*, I would like to change the `delay` value as well, each time `iframe src` has been updated.

The new `delay` number will be a **random** number between **15** & **30** secs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

Comment: @Liam Its not a duplicate topic. In that topic, you are generating a random number only. What I looking for is to update `setInterval` `delay` value by having `Interval` for itself as well in `jQuery`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change an interval once it's been defined. A workaround for this would be to chain `setTimeout()` calls, generating a random delay between each call something like this:

```js
var locations = ['http://link1.com', 'http://link2.com', 'http://link3.com'];
var i = 0;

setTimeout(setSrc, getDelay());

function setSrc() {
  console.log(locations[++i % locations.length]);
  setTimeout(setSrc, getDelay());
}

function getDelay() {
  var delay = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 15) * 1000;
  console.log('waiting: ' + delay);
  return delay;
}
```

> How can I make it so when loop is done, it stops?

In this case you can check if `i > locations.length` and then not call the function again:

```
function setSrc() {
  console.log(locations[++i]);
  if (i < locations.length)
    setTimeout(setSrc, getDelay());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rory. Works great :) . I have only one question. I only want to run the loop once and I managed to do this by doing `iframe.attr("src", locations[++i])` in my `setSrc()` function. Is it correct? and I see that after I have done the loop once, `getDelay()` function still runs. How can I make it so when loop is done, it does stop. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a bunch :)